# Python Function to Fractionize digits of many tuples contained within a list

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
> AA = [('JAMES', 124), ('KATE', 78), ('MARIE', 62), ('NGUYEN', 59)]
> 
> BB = [('JACK', 133), ('JILL', 68), ('SARAH', 67), ('MARGARITA', 66),
> ('NATE', 66), ('DANI', 55)]
> 
> CC =[('MARYLOU', 155), ('PETER', 98), ('ALEXA', 57), ('MARK', 54),
> ('KAREN', 34)]
```

I have a lot of lists (AA, BB and CC) containing tuples containing a string and corresponding digit.

For each list (such as AA, BB and CC), I want the function to take the highest digit (124 in the list AA) in these tuples as 1, and output the remaining digits of all other tuples in the same list as fraction of the highest digit among the tuples (78/124=0.63). Fractions should be 2 decimal points.

Target Output

```
AA = [('JAMES', 1), ('KATE', 0.63), ('MARIE', 0.5), ('NGUYEN', 0.48)]

BB = [('JACK', 1), ('JILL', 0.51), ('SARAH', 0.5), ('MARGARITA', 0.5), ('NATE', 0.5), ('DANI', 0.41)]

CC =[('MARYLOU', 1), ('PETER', 0.63), ('ALEXA', 0.37), ('MARK', 0.35), ('KAREN', 0.22)]
```

Please suggest tips to solve this problem.

So far, I came up with the ranking of tuples inside each list.

```
def rank(L): #to sort tuples inside the List by the value inside the tuples
    L = L.sort(reverse = True, key = lambda x : x[1])
```

Comment: This sounds like homework. Have you started any code that attempts a solution?

Comment: its not homework, I am doing genomic data analysis, can't wrap my head around defining functions for objects inside objects.

Comment: If you don't have any code to show us where you are stuck, check the answer below and tell us what parts you get stuck on. Break the one-liner in to step-by-step parts and put it into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips:

- Find the maximum value in each list. You can do that by sorting it by the second value.
- Loop through the list and divide each number by the value you got above
- Use round(value,2) to round to 2 decimal places

If you cant get it, this should help you in step 2 and 3:

> `return map(lambda x : (x[0],)+(round(float(x[1])/list1[0][1],2),),list1)`

#### EDIT:

```
AA = [('JAMES', 124), ('KATE', 78), ('MARIE', 62), ('NGUYEN', 59)]

def rank(L):
    L.sort(reverse = True, key = lambda x : x[1])
    return L

def normalize(L):
    L = rank(L)
    newlist = []    #The new list
    for i in L:     #Iterate through the sorted list
        newtuple = (i[0],)    #Copy the name as is
        newtuple += (round(float(i[1])/L[0][1],2),)  #Divide by the largest value and round to 2 decimal places
        newlist.append(newtuple)    #Add it to the new list
    return newlist

AA = normalize(AA)
print AA
#[('JAMES', 1.0), ('KATE', 0.63), ('MARIE', 0.5), ('NGUYEN', 0.48)]
```

Comment: hey Rohit, are you from NTU Singapore?

Comment: I added the sorting function. How can I do the step 2: looping through each list?
@RohithS98

Comment: No I am not from NTU. Since you are using a list of tuples, you will need to create a new list. Go through the elements of the first list with for loop and copy the name as it is while changing the second value. You can also use list comprehension like in my answer.

Comment: You lost me. can you show example similar question asked on before similar to "Go through the elements of the first list with for loop and copy the name as it is while changing the second value. " @RohithS98

Comment: @Nguyen I added a program which explains each steps in the comments